# Debugging/identifying Java issues without a debugger

Tags: java, debugging

I want to be able to identify an exception at a running Java code without attaching a debugger. For a simple example, if I have the following code:

```
    int i = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    while (true)
    {
        i++;
        int number = rand.nextInt(1000);
        if (number == 20)
            throw new Exception("Error!!!");
    }
```

How can I know the value of "i" at the time of the exception throw? (without attaching any debuggers or adding log/print entries).

My motivation is that I want to be able to identify a problem at a customer site without attaching any debuggers to the production site.

If Someone was asking the same question using .Net or C++ I could get the value of "i" using Windbg and the relevant PDBs

Thanks!

Comment: I have a TV and I want to watch a series without turning it on. Wish me good luck!

Comment: Hmm, no debuggers AND no logging you say. Good luck finding the value of 'i' in the RAM :P

Comment: `i` will be probably 0. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut: Mind=blown. I was so baffled by this question I haven't even read the code xD

Comment: I forgot adding the i++. That not the point here....

Comment: I don't believe it is impossible. If Someone was asking the same question in .Net or C++ I could get the value of "i" using windbg. My motivation is that I want to be able to identify a problem at a customer site without attaching any debuggers to the production site. This is nothing like wathing a TV series without a TV :|

Comment: You should have just said that from the start. Your question was vague and thus the downvotes. You wrote "no debuggers", yet now you say you can use them (yes, windbg is a debugger). That's the reason for these comments.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Either you log, you add more information to your exception messages, or you debug. What part of this are you unclear about?

Answer (score 3):

Add the relevant information to the `Exception` object.

```
if (number == 20)
    throw new Exception("Error!!! i = " + i);
```

You can retrieve the value of `i` in the `catch` block, using `Exception.getMessage()` (and some string parsing, in this case; alternatively, just `throw new Exception("" + i)`).

Comment: +1 although I'm not sure if this doesn't violate the given restrictions (no logging).

Comment: I'm not sure either, hopefully Omri will clarify that.

Comment: This also doesn't answer my question. My motivation is that I want to be able to identify a problem at a customer site without attaching any debuggers to the production site.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.

If you are actually asking how you can find out information about the execution state of a program without either attaching a debugger or modifying the program to add logging / tracing / whatever that will give you that information .... then the answer is "You can't do it".

In that situation, your only option is to attempt to reason about the program's behaviour.

---

In your example, the random number generator returns numbers that are (for all practical purposes) unpredictable, and therefore not amenable to reasoning.  And that would *normally* be the end of it.

However, @Thomas Jungblut's comment points out that this is irrelevant, and the answer is ZERO ... because nothing in your program changes the value of `i` after it has been initialized.

But this really doesn't alter the "general" answer:

- If you can't trace it / debug it, you have to reason about it.
- If you can't reason about it, you are stuck.